# React Native Paper HelperText consumes space when invisible

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

I am displaying error messages for input fields with React Native Paper, and I am using the [HelperText](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/helper-text.html). This is my code:

```
      <TextInput
        mode="outlined"
        label="Password"
        placeholder="Password"
        value={Password}
        secureTextEntry={true}
        onChangeText={onChangePassword}
        style={{height: 40}}
      />
      <HelperText type="error" visible={isSubmit && PasswordValid()}>
        {password_message}
      </HelperText>
```

And with no error message it displays like this, and the `helperText` consumes a space  (I did inspect it as well, there is a space) even it is invisible.

[image]

And this when it is visible:

[image]

How do I get rid of the white space when it is invisible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditionally render it

```
{isTrue ? <HelperText type="error" visible={isSubmit && PasswordValid()}>
  {password_message}
</HelperText> : null}
```

This won't mount the element to the views until the `isTrue` value is true hence no empty space.

In your case you can do something like this

```
{isSubmit && PasswordValid() ? <HelperText type="error" visible={true}>
      {password_message}
    </HelperText> : null}
```

Make sure `isSubmit && PasswordValid()` is a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a dynamic styling based on the visibility of the error or try as follows. Change margin value according to your need

```
 <View style={{marginVertical:-3}}><HelperText type="error" visible={isSubmit && PasswordValid()}>
    {password_message}</View>
```

or

Conditional rendering.

```
{hasErrorVisible ?<View> <HelperText type="error" visible={isSubmit && PasswordValid()}>
  {password_message}
</HelperText></View> : null}
```